# Cannot publish Composite Locator to ArcGIS Server 10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, enterprise-geodatabase, geocoding

I am unable to publish a composite locator from a 10.0 SP5 ArcSDE Geodatabase (Oracle) to ArcGIS Server 10.2.2. To narrow down the problem I created a fresh composite locator with only one component locator to keep it as simple as possible.  I am able to successfully publish the component locator but not the composite.

When publishing, the packaging is successful and then at the very end of the process I get the message "Failed to publish service".  In the ArcGIS Server logs I get the errors below:

```
Failed to create the service.: ERROR: code:404, Could not find resource or operation 
'Composite_Address_Streets.GeocodeServer' on the system., No resource could be found 
at that address.


Error executing tool.: ERROR 001487: Failed to update the published service with the 
server-side data location. Please see the server's log for more details. ERROR 
001369: Failed to create the service. Failed to execute (Publish Service Definition).
```

I am however able to create the .sd file.  If I try to upload it to server using the Upload Service Definition GP tool I get the same error as above.

A few more notes:

I am publishing the service through the "owner" connection to SDE so the privileges should not be an issue. Also, the component locator is referenced in the composite via the owner connection as well.

I have registered the SDE data source correctly and do not get any suspicious messages during the analysis step.  The only message is that the composite locator will be copied to the server which is normal since they are always copied to the server.

I am able to publish the same composite locator with a copy of the data from a 10.2 file geodatabase so it looks like it's just an SDE/ArcGIS 10.2.2 issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticket with ESRI and there is apparently a similar known issue.

Bug NIM-099335
Synopsis
ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.1 fails to publish a composite address locator from a registered Spatial Database Engine (SDE) database on ArcGIS for Server 10.1 or higher.

Even though the versions are slightly different, this is the same problem. As a workaround I copied the composite locator to a file geodatabase in a registered folder and published from there.  The composite locator still references other locators which are in ArcSDE.